# How can I count how many times Thread has been suspended

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm making a very simple program in java, even because I'm a student. I made a program that count 1 at 1000, and when the number is multiple for 2 the thread is suspended for about 500ms. That's ok. But in the final, I need to show how many times the thread has been suspended. Like

```
System.out.println("The thread has been suspended for: " );
```

I have no idea. I appreciate any help.

```
@Override
public void run () {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(500);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadNumeros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("thread has been suspended for: ");
}
```

Comment: any code to show?

Comment: @TusharSharma, sorry. I edited.

Comment: Do you mean counting how many times did you call the `sleep()`? If so just use a counter (as a generalisation, of course, you can know that it will go there 500 times in advance). On the other hand, if you mean how many times the thread was suspended by _any_ reason, then that's a different thing.

Comment: @cbuchart, Yes, I want to do how many times the thread was suspended by any reason. I think the solution below is right, isn't? Have other way to solve this? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DO NOT MIX (SUSPENDED) WITH (SLEEP): they work differently.

`Thread.sleep()` sends the current thread into the "Not
 Runnable" state for some amount of time. The thread keeps the monitors
 it has acquired -- i.e. if the thread is currently in a synchronized
 block or method no other thread can enter this block or method. If
 another thread calls `t.interrupt()` it will wake up the sleeping
 thread.

`t.suspend()` is deprecated. Using it is possible to halt a
 thread other than the current thread. A suspended thread keeps all its
 monitors and since this state is not interruptable it is deadlock
 prone.

`stop(), suspend(), resume()` are the methods used for thread
 implementation. `stop()` - terminate the thread execution, Once a thread
 is stopped, it cannot be restarted with the `start()` method, since
 `stop()` will terminate the execution of a thread. Instead you can pause
 the execution of a thread with the `sleep()` method. The thread will
 sleep for a certain period of time and then begin executing when the
 time limit is reached. But, this is not ideal if the thread needs to
 be started when a certain event occurs. In this case, the `suspend()`
 method allows a thread to temporarily cease executing. `resume()` method
 allows the suspended thread to start again.

**Synchronization-:** If you declare any method as `synchronized`, it is known as a 'synchronized method'.

A synchronized method is used to lock an object for any shared resource.

When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires
 the lock for that object and releases it when the thread completes its
 task.

**TRY LIKE THIS-:**

```
@Override
public void run() {
int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println(i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
                count+=1

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ThreadNumeros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("thread has been suspended for: "+count);

}
```

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm. Really thanks! @TusharSharma. So simple, And I could not understand. Keep Studying! Thanks again.

Comment: @Cavalerio No issues mate

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted. Use code formatting for text that is code.